# How can I keep the brigtness on call?

Tags: react-native, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am builded video call app with agora.io. but after a while the screen light turns off on both sides. I just have to keep the screens on during the video call. How can I do this without using plugins? I could not find such a thing in the agora documents.

Answer (score 0):

this functionality is not provided by Agora. You have to use other external libraries for doing this. Expo keep awake is a fantastic solution. https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-keep-awake

Make sure you have configured [unimodules](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/react-native-unimodules) first before installing expo packages.